# Admin Forcing Logout

Tags: admin, error

I'm having an issue where the admin is kicking a user out after an indefinite period of time. The corresponding error message is

**Tried to restore session from a cookie, but the given hashed database token value does not appear to belong to the given login name. Hashed db value: 5740fb357a555db6a1ee9e9ea2160179daeed342czozMjoiWjdzUk94ZHVSZGJlMEVOT2JyUFJxcmxkY01FeGhoeU0iOw== and loginName: omitted for stack exchange.**

A few minutes later I see another error:

**2016/01/19 21:53:16 [error] [application] Tried to read the folder contents of /home/domain.com/craft/storage/runtime/cache/, but could not.
2016/01/19 21:53:16 [error] [application] Tried to read the folder contents of /home/domain.com/craft/storage/runtime/assets/, but could not.
2016/01/19 21:53:16 [error] [application] Tried to read the folder contents of /home/domain.com/craft/storage/runtime/temp/, but could not.**

My craft directory is installed above my public_html directory.

Here are some things I've tried:

1. Verified permissions [755] for the app, config and storage directories.
2. Set overridePhpSession = true
3. Set userSessionDuration = false

I have not been able to duplicate the error, so at this point I would have to say the error is only effecting 1 user. I had him try a different browser (chrome was previously using IE) and clear his cookies as well. The error still happened in chrome.

Any suggestions you have are appreciated.

Comment: Is it a particular user or all users?

Comment: I have not been able to duplicate the error, so at this point I would have to say it is only effecting 1 user. I had him try a different browser (chrome) and clear his cookies as well.